# Is there a desktop application programming language that works like Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: development-environment, graphical-programming

[Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) a graphical programming environment, mostly designed for manipulating information found on the web, where functions are represented by blocks connected by pipes. Certain types of data are piped into a block, and the block has some options you set, and then other types of data flow out of a block. In normal programming terms, blocks are functions, inputs are parameters, outputs are return values, and options are constants inside the function.

Are there any environments for building standalone (desktop, mobile, console, etc) applications that work like this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about standalone, but [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) by MIT is a pretty neat way to build code via drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

[Game Editor](http://game-editor.com/) is an obscure example, for designing cross-platform games. More object-oriented than functional, but still a graphical environment with connected elements that affect each other.